# Transposing a data table properly

Tags: excel, transform, transpose

I have a table that has an odd structure, and I can't for the life of me transpose/transform it properly.
I even have KuTools, and still can't figure it out.

My table looks like this:

[image]

There are 55 unique users, each has 10 trials (but errors exists so number not fixed), and they have three entries per trial.

I would like to make this into a table where it goes:

UserID | Participant | Trial | Token 1 | Token 2 | Token 3 | Original | Chosen

And then has 10 entries/rows per User (one for each trial).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I usually create a key column on the left of my data that can be used in a vlookup on another sheet.  Your key would be UserID-Participant-Trial-Token.  Create a unique list of these keys and then use vlookup to pull the values that you want to see.  If this doesn't make sense then I can post an aswer with more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got desperate so I just transposed each 3 elements in the Token list, and then matched them to their respective trial and user id. It was doable given the database size, but I would not use this as a solution if I had thousands of entries. (even here I had to check for irregularities by hand...)